# My if function not wokring properly in ASP NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I try to make an if function in razor view, by comparing two data from viewbag in ASP NET MVC
@ver comes from ViewBag.Temp

```
<td class="text-center">
    @foreach (Dummy ver in ViewBag.dummies)
    {
      if (@ver.Name == @item.Name)
      {
         <i class="fas fa-check" id="existed"></i>
      }
    }
</td>
```

I already have 2 same name data inside those 2 tables but it wont work

[The Temp data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6PFG.png)

[The Dummies Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaYpk.png)

but when i call another data it works properly

[Another data temp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A08JJ.png)

[Another data Dummies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1vC3.png)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'it wont work'?  What happens?

Comment: i will edit to add the photo

Comment: you need to use `@if()`

Comment: still not working, im not using the `@if` because the if is inside `@foreach` already.

Comment: sorry, I ignore it.

Comment: What is `@item` inside if?

Answer (score 0):

It solved, there is some human error on the data that have white space on leading or trailing then im using `trim()` function on my view

look like this

```
<td class="text-center">
                        @foreach (Dummy ver in ViewBag.Dummies)
                        {
                                var tem = @item.Name.Trim();
                                if (@ver.Name.Trim() == tem)
                            {
                                <i class="fas fa-check" id="existed"></i>
                            }
                        }
                    </td>
```